# vuex must call Vue.use(Vuex) before creating a store instance

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component, vuex

I have a `store.js`

```
import Vuex from 'vuex';

export default new Vuex.Store({
  state: { customers: [] },
  mutations: {
    addCustomer (customer) {
      state.customers.push(customer);
    }
  }
});
```

In my `main.js` I'm referring the store like this, but `vue-devtools` always return `[vuex] must call Vue.use(Vuex) before creating a store instance.`:

```
import Vue from 'vue';
import Vuex from 'vuex';
Vue.use(Vuex);    
import store from './store'
new Vue({
  store,
  render: h => h(App),
}).$mount('#app');
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're missing to add the following imports in your `store.js` :

```
    import Vue from 'vue';
    import Vuex from 'vuex';

     Vue.use(Vuex);
      export default new Vuex.Store({ ...
```